# Unable to open Linux ISO file

Tags: macos, disk-utility, iso

how can I open / modify a (linux) ISO?

If I try to open it via DiskUtility it says `The disk you attached was not readable by this computer`.

The image is the current release of ArchLinux: https://www.archlinux.de/download

Comment: The format of the image is likely not supported by macOS. Just like Windows doesn't natively read APFS, macOS likely does not read whatever format that disk is.

Comment: Do you have an Intel or an M1 Mac?

Comment: @nohillside M1 MacbookAir. Steve How can I open it? I need to modify the boot ISO

Comment: Using https://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/ to boot an ARM-based Linux system and accessing the ISO from there might work.

Comment: Lol you are joking

Comment: An ISO isn't something you "open"... it's a filesystem.  So if you want to modify it, you need to recreate it.  The easiest way to do that is to do it where it's supported.

Comment: If you want to be able to read/write to it [though without any guarantee you can repack the ISO itself you'll need ExtFS software - https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/ ISOs are not native to Mac & neither is ExtFS.

Comment: As long as it’s not corrupted, an ISO is a container, [when you attach it, how many file systems does it contain](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/61779/5472)?

Answer (score 2):

On my M1 Mac with macOS 12.3 (Monterey), double-clicking the ISO produces no result. You have to use the terminal to attach the image, (optionally) create a mount point and mount the filesystem.

Attach the ISO to a loop device:

```
$ hdiutil attach -nomount ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.img
/dev/disk4           GUID_partition_scheme
/dev/disk4s1         Microsoft Basic Data
/dev/disk4s2         EFI
/dev/disk4s3         Microsoft Basic Data
```

Then arrange the mount:

```
$ mkdir -p ubuntu
$ mount -t cd9660 /dev/disk4s1 ./ubuntu
$ ls -l ubuntu
```

If you use a multipart ISO, you can concatenate the files together (this may or may not work):

```
$ cat part1.iso part2.iso > merged.iso
```